# Is it possible to limit the logs retrieved from GAE Logging API?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to paginate the logs retrieved from the GAE Logging API? The largest GAE node only has 1 gig of memory and I suspect we are getting `OutOfMemory` Exceptions.

I would like to retrieve only the first part of the logs and then use an offset to get the rest.

Is anything like this possible with the GAE logs API?

Comment: Please show an example of the code that is misbehaving, and symptoms of the problem such as extracts from server logs.

Answer (score 0):

The [AppEngine Java Log API example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/#Java_Getting_log_data) demonstrates pagination with a variable offset.  The lines:

```
if (++i >= limit) {
    break;
}
```

are supposed to limit the initial and subsequent retrievals to for example 5 records at a time.

Comment: There is no way to limit the original query. If say there are 100 MB you will get all of them for the first query and then will have an offset for subsequent requests. Unless I am missing something this does not help work around the memory constraints on GAE boxes.

Comment: Highlighted the implementation of limit from the example.

Comment: The lines you have added are just counting the result set already pulled into memory as a result of the query. This is not limiting the result returned by the API. Hence will not help with memory issues.

Comment: Do you think the iterable returned by LogServiceFactory.getLogService().fetch(query) loads all log records into memory before the code retrieves the first record?  I think not.